# Set mongodb configuration path using mongodb.config in Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, configuration, yaml

I am trying to set up `mongodb 2.6.3` on Windows,I have installed it and would like to configure the `dbpath` using a `mongodb.config` file at `C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin`

I have tried adding it like this:

```
 dbpath=E:\Do\mongodb
```

I have also tried to add it like this[(tested it in `YAML Parser` online)](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=-+storage%3A%0A+++-+++dbPath%3A%22E%3A%5CDo%5Cmongodb%22&type=json):

```
- storage:
   -   dbPath:"E:\Do\mongodb"
```

It seems like neither of these works,how can I set up `config` options for my `mongodb`.It does not even seem to be recognizing the configuration file,I even tried it mongod --config but it did not work.

Comment: Check the encoding of the `.cfg` file. Mine was `UTF-16 LE with BOM`, and after saving with `UTF-8`, it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me, using :

```
dbpath=T:\data\db
```

My mongodb version is also 2.6.3

By the way, my config file is named "mongod.cfg", but yours is "mongodb.config". Maybe this counts.

Anyway, try to follow the tutorial:http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/   It works

Answer (score 2):

> when you write the config file with "" i.e double quotes you should use \\ instead of \ for windows... Otherwise you will find that there is "unknown escape character" in this line of the config file

```
- storage:
   -   dbPath:"E:\\Do\\mongodb"
```

Comment: when you write the config file with "" you should use \\ instead of \ for windows.